# How to get all (IIS) websites status/state from remote machine using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iis

I was trying to read the status of IIS website from remotely. I tried below code.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName
$block = { 
import-module 'webAdministration'
Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites
}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $block  | Out-File -append $WebreportPath
```

But above command given me only Websites with https binding, when it comes to https it throws below error.

```
The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I am trying to renmote a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.
Please guide me. Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this will help for someone. Below is my findings and the answer.

Powershell sends only objects remotely, and render them using available templates.
So need to give a template accordingly. I used "Format-Table".
Be-careful, if you use "Format-Table" outside it results same error. Remember to use it inside the scriptblock.

Error-prone:

```
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $serverName { Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites} | Format-Table | Out-File -append $WebreportPath
```

Correct code:

```
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $serverName { Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites | Format-Table} | Out-File -append $WebreportPath
```

My refers : 
[http://forums.iis.net/t/1155059.aspx?IIS+provider+and+PowerShell+remoting](http://forums.iis.net/t/1155059.aspx?IIS%20provider%20and%20PowerShell%20remoting)

Good Luck !

Comment: This will work around the data transfer issue, but no you're only writing the output, and losing the object structure for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some problem with retrieving the objects using a remote session, but that is no blocking issue (I have run into this as well).

To prevent the error from being written, you can use `-ErrorAction` like this:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName

$block = { 
    Import-Module 'webAdministration'
    Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites
}

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ScriptBlock $block | 
    Out-File -append $WebreportPath
```

This way you will not see the remoting error, but you will still receive the data you need.

Note that this hides all errors, so you are possibly hiding an error that you may want to see. For that you will need a fix for the underlying ptoblem, so you can remove the `-ErrorAction` patch.